# Error saying PostgreSQL database table doesn't exist when it is created in the entrypoint script - DOCKER COMPOSE and POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, datatable, psycopg2

I am completely new to Docker and Docker compose and I have encountered issue which I don't know how to solve.
I am trying to make a simple app which shows some items from my existing postgres database on the localhost:8080. Everything works fine, so further on I want to put this app into Docker containers using Docker compose. I used dump to get apartments.sql file, which I am trying to load to the postgres docker container by using VOLUMES, but I am getting an error that says that the table that I am trying to access doesn't exist. My app code is:

```
def get_db_connection():
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='db',
                        user='postgres',
                        password='pass',
                        port = '5432')
return conn
```

```
    @app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM maki;')
    # save the data into the variable called items
    items = cur.fetchall()
    new_items = tuples_to_list(items)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', new_items=new_items)
if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080,debug=True)
```

When I run it locally, it connects to my local database and works normally.
My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 web:
  build: ./flask_app
  ports:
  - 8080:8080
  volumes:
  - ./:/app
  depends_on:
    - db

 db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - 5432:5432
  environment:
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_DB=apartments



  volumes:
  - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./data/apartments.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/apartments.sql
  container_name: postgresdb
 

volumes:
  data:
   driver: local
```

where in the folder apartments.sql I put the dumped apartments.sql which has table named maki. I get the following error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "maki" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM maki;

I am not sure if this is the right approach, or in general, how should I do this in order for docker compose to work properly and show me the items on localhost:8080? What am I supposed to do with the index.html file in docker?

My dumped apartments.sql file:

```
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.7
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.7

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: maki; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.maki (
    name character varying(255),
    image text
);


ALTER TABLE public.maki OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Data for Name: maki; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY public.maki (name, image) FROM stdin;
Prodej bytu 3+kk 79\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gY_m/AQF296.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 60\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gV_p/VBhduS.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 98\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gT_o/kPyBHP.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 120\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2 (Mezonet)\\ https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gX_l/r7TKmQ.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 81\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gT_p/7XDIio.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 55\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gW_m/eBNBuKo.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
Prodej bytu 3+kk 75\\\\u00a0m\\\\u00b2\\    https://d18-a.sdn.cz/d_18/c_img_gS_n/xcgCeK.jpeg?fl=res,400,300,3|shr,,20|jpg,90
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM apartments.maki` execute correctly?

Comment: I get the same error : psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "apartments.maki" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM apartments.maki;

Comment: Can you attach your `apartments.sql`?

Comment: @plplmax I have attached it in the question now.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM public.maki` execute correctly?

Comment: @plplmax Exactly the same error again

Comment: Is the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` folder empty before trying to execute the `.sql` script?

Comment: @plplmax Yes, it's empty, there's nothing in data folder. Now I see that  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is empty too, which shouldn't be?

Comment: hmm, can you try to delete redundant empty lines before `db.volumes`?

Comment: @plplmax Didn't help